# Payment Processor Error message 9003: MD5 Verification failed after upgrade

Tags: civicontribute

After the recent upgrade to 4.6.9, I am getting this error when processing secure Authorize.net payments:

Payment Processor Error message
9003: MD5 Verification failed

My payment processor settings appear to be correct, including API Login, Payment Key, MD5 Hash and Site URL. I am using the Drupal 7 CMS and both settings.php and civicrm.settings.php are correct.

No other issues exist after the upgrade.

*Edit:

I suspect the MD5 Hash value is wrong here, which has always been recorded as my store_id. Should this be a transaction key, or does the hash value come from Authorize.net? Here's a snip from my log file:

```
    Nov 03 09:27:04  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Invalid value passed to getPayment function
    [code] =>
)

Nov 03 09:27:04  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(364): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

1. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php(188): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Invalid value passed to getPayment function")
2. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php(349): CRM_Financial_BAO_PaymentProcessor::getPayment("", "live")
3. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.php(73): CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->preProcess()
4. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main->preProcess()
5. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
6. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), "display")
7. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main), "display")
8. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
9. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
10. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
11. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
12. /home/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
13. [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contribute", "transact")
14. /home/example.com/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
15. /home/example.com/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
16. {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The ca.civicrm.moneris extension folder was deleted during the drush civicrm-upgrade process.

As a result, my "Moneris Credit Card" Payment Processor Type disappeared and defaulted to Authorize.net (which uses an MD5 hash algorithm) after the upgrade. After restoring this, I entered my API token as opposed to the store admin password in the Payment Processor Edit form and my transactions are now working again. I have renamed this field label to "API Token."

Comment: Would you mind helping me understand how you fixed your problem? I'm dealing with a similar issue, and maybe this is the answer!. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12465/payment-processor-error-9003-and-loggging