# Payment Processor Error 9003, and logging

Tags: payment-processor, error, authorize.net, logging

I have the same issue that [this person did](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/payment-processor-error-message-9003-md5-verification-failed-after-upgrade), though I'm updated to 4.6.10 The issue is that when submitting payments, I get the 9003 error code, which says "MD5 Verification failed."  I've reset the MD5 code from both sides, and am confident that they match. It's possible that my issue could be solved with the answer that I linked, but I don't know enough to apply it. It's also possible that Authorize.net tech support could help me, but they won't do anything without the log and I'm unsure where it lives. So...

1) Do you know how to fix this error?

Or failing that,

2) Where are CiviCRM's payment processor logs?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and correct the version number (4.10) which you've reported? There isn't (yet) such a CiviCRM version, and an accurate answer will be more likely with an accurate question.

Comment: Good catch! Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering (2) only here.

CiviCRM's payment processor logs vary in their location based on the CMS in use. These logfiles include a unique string per site, as the logfiles are  located within the webroot and a hard to guess filename offers some defense against attackers viewing debug output.

This is documented @ -

- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles
- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CMS+Standard+Directories+and+File+locations

### WordPress

4.6 and below: `wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.HARDTOGUESS.log`
4.7 and above: `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.HARDTOGUESS.log`

### Joomla

`media/com_civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.HARDTOGUESS.log` ([1](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles)) or
`media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.HARDTOGUESS.log` ([2](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CMS+Standard+Directories+and+File+locations))

### Drupal

`sites/<sitedir>/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.HARDTOGUESS.log`

Comment: I don't think the web-accessible logfiles are great even with the current protections applied, and I'm working to provide better options in [CRM-13639](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13639).

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question: If this log shows only email related errors and nothing about the payment processor that is acting up, what would you take from that information?

Comment: I'd check if the Authorize.NET payment processor logs to a separate file; next I'd track down the location of that error message (capitalisation of **V**erification may make the location distinctive?) and debug what specific inputs aren't matching, leading to a validation failure.

Comment: Correction for Joomla: ```~/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/```

Comment: Thanks BruceW! Looks like [Debugging for Developers](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-Logfiles) and [CMS Standard directories](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CMS+Standard+Directories+and+File+locations#CMSStandardDirectoriesandFilelocations-Joomla!) differ re Joomla! locations, hope someone who uses Joomla can check and correct the wiki docs. Updated the above to mention both for now, let me know if I should trim it down again.